# Need help with some regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to port some simple [eregi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) regular expressions to [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for PHP 5.3/6.0 compilance.

Since I'm not too confident in my regular expression porting skills I need some help...

**#1**

Old version:

```
if( eregi('foo',$myVar) ) {
    $aresult = explode('/',stristr($myVar,'foo'));
    $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
}
```

New version:

```
if( preg_match('/Foo\/([^ ]*)/i',$myVar,$matches) ) {
    $aversion = $matches[1];
}
```

**#2**

Old version:

```
if( eregi('bar',$myVar) && ! eregi('rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]',$myVar)) {
    $aresult = explode('/',stristr($myVar,'bar'));
    $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
}
```

New version:

```
//Not done yet need help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second snippet is pretty much the same as the first, just with that extra condition.  I'm going to guess that your actual code (or how you want it to work) is a little different to that presented? If so, could you elaborate on those differences please?

Either way, your #2 could look similar to #1.

```
if (preg_match('~bar/([^ ]*)~i', $myVar, $match) && ! preg_match('/rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]/', $myVar)) {
    $aversion = $match[1];
}
```

---

<sup>The use of `~` as the [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) might seem strange; the reasoning being that the regular expression contains the most usual delimiting character (`/`) so an alternative is used instead of escaping the slash as you did in the question.</sup>

Comment: #1 and #2 are different (yet similar) problems. I already ported #1, but I'm not sure of my implementation. For #2, I will need help to do it.

Comment: My current answer translated you #2 into a `preg_match`-using snippet akin to your #1 (which is fine). If you have a specific question, problem or task that you want solved then please elaborate. As it stands, I've done what you appear to be asking about.

Comment: Just a question in your answer I can put "bar" in any case (Bar, BAR, bAr...) and it will match (beasause ~i)?